# How to pass parameter from fastlane to shell file

Tags: bash, shell, sh, fastlane

I am tring to pass two parameters from fastfile to shell script file

**Fastlane lane code**

```
lane :upload_file do |options|

_versionCode = options[:versionCode]
_versionName = options[:versionName]

puts "version code = #{_versionCode} version name = #{_versionName}"
sh 'bash ./scripts/upload_file_to_server.sh "$_versionCode" "$_versionName"'
end
```

**upload_file_to_server.sh file**

```
#!/bin/bash
main() {
versionName="$_versionName"
versoinCode ="$_versionCode"

echo "versionname = $versionName versioncode = $versionCode"

}

main
```

```
Excecuting : fastlane upload_file versionCode:1 versionName:1.1.1

Not able to get versionName and versionCode in shell script file.
```

Any solution for this ?

Comment: I don't know anything about the language you are using to call sh but for this to work you would have to define versionName and versionCode as environment variables before calling your script

Comment: `am tring to pass two parameters` Cool, but your bash script ignores any parameters. Actually use them, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, parameters are accessed using `$1`, `$2` etc.  You have to fetch these parameters in order to use them; they don't magically appear in your local variables.

The same applies to functions. Hence, in your function `main`, do a

```
local versionName="$1"
local versionCode="$2"
```

and when calling your function, do a

```
main "$1" "$2"
```

Comment: Or more succinctly `main "$@"` to pass an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: Yes, if the OP really wants to pass all arguments to his function. Maybe he doesn't want to .... because in this way, creating a function for this purpose is pretty pointless. That's why I wrote the parameters explicitly.